# I am looking for help on a recently broken small element of code using Selenium xpath?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

player_ids = ['44', '8', '100']
rd_id = 1

dictionary = {'Hole Number': [],
              'Id': [],
              'Player name': [],
              'Shot number': [],
              'Shot details': []}

# iterating through player_ids

name_list = []
hole_num_list = []
id_list = []
shot_data_final = []
shot_num_list = []



for i in player_ids:
    team_id = i
    base_url = "https://bet365.apps.imgarena.com/golf/3.20.1/full/?eventId=300&language=en&options=eyJ2aWRlb1BsYXliYWNrRW5hYmxlZCI6ZmFsc2V9#/leaderboard/team/"
    mid_url = "?roundNo="
    end_url = "&holeNo=1"
    team_url = base_url + str(team_id) + mid_url + str(rd_id) + end_url

    driver.get(team_url)

    shotsbtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span[1]')))
    shotsbtn.click()

    #   iterating through each hole 1-18

    for i in range(1, 4):
        hole_id = i
        base_xpath = '//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div['
        end_xpath = ']'
        full_xpath = base_xpath + str(hole_id) + end_xpath

        sleep(randint(1, 3))

        holebtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, full_xpath)))
        holebtn.click()

        sleep(randint(1, 3))

        content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

        name = soup.find('div', class_="player-name__-5d9467f0").text

        hole_num = int(soup.find('span', class_="inner__-2a6dfbd6").text)

        shot_data = soup.find('ul', class_="list__31f35e88").find_all('li')

        for shot in shot_data:
            shott = shot.text.split(':')
            shot_num = shott[0]
            shot_num_list.append(shot_num)
            shot_data_final.append(shott[-1].strip())

        for x in range(len(shot_data_final) - len(id_list)):
            name_list.append(name)
            hole_num_list.append(hole_num)
            id_list.append(team_id)

        hole_num_list.append('')
        id_list.append('')
        name_list.append('')
        shot_num_list.append('')
        shot_data_final.append('')

driver.close()
dictionary['Hole Number'] = hole_num_list
dictionary['Id'] = id_list
dictionary['Player name'] = name_list
dictionary['Shot number'] = shot_num_list
dictionary['Shot details'] = shot_data_final

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

df.to_csv('Shots.csv', index=False)
```

This code has been working great for a couple of months but I think just recently some of the site code was changed.

I'm very new to using Selenium and I'm a bit confused as to which element is causing the issue below.

The problem I have now is that the 'Hole Number' appears not to be appending the list (1 to 18)??

I'm getting this output:

[image]

But I'm looking for this type of output:
[image]

I'm sure it's in this region of code but I'm stumped for now. I will get there eventually but any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Is it something to do with xpath="1" in front of the text that I'm attempting to scrape?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya looks like the class changes to "active". Why don't you just grab the text of the `holebtn`?

so change:

```
hole_num = int(soup.find('span', class_="inner__-2a6dfbd6").text)
```

to:

```
hole_num = int(holebtn.text)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
   Hole Number   Id     Player name Shot number                                             Shot details
0            1   44   Sean, Crocker      Shot 3                                   in the hole for Birdie
1            1   44   Sean, Crocker      Shot 2       stroke 2, 49 yds to Green, 10 ft 1 in. left to pin
2            1   44   Sean, Crocker      Shot 1         stroke 1, 323 yds to Fairway, 51 yds left to pin
3                                                                                                       
4            2   44   Sean, Crocker      Shot 3                                      in the hole for Par
5            2   44   Sean, Crocker      Shot 2   stroke 2, 30 ft 3 in. to Green, 2 ft 4 in. left to pin
6            2   44   Sean, Crocker      Shot 1     stroke 1, 240 yds to Green, 27 ft 11 in. left to pin
7                                                                                                       
8            3   44   Sean, Crocker      Shot 4                                      in the hole for Par
9            3   44   Sean, Crocker      Shot 3   stroke 3, 30 ft 2 in. to Green, 1 ft 8 in. left to pin
10           3   44   Sean, Crocker      Shot 2     stroke 2, 151 yds to Green, 31 ft 10 in. left to pin
11           3   44   Sean, Crocker      Shot 1        stroke 1, 285 yds to Fairway, 157 yds left to pin
12                                                                                                      
13           1    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 4                                      in the hole for Par
14           1    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 3  stroke 3, 32 ft 11 in. to Green, 3 ft 2 in. left to pin
15           1    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 2      stroke 2, 100 yds to Green, 31 ft 8 in. left to pin
16           1    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 1          stroke 1, 264 yds to Rough, 110 yds left to pin
17                                                                                                      
18           2    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 3                                      in the hole for Par
19           2    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 2         stroke 2, 9 yds to Green, 3 ft 4 in. left to pin
20           2    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 1       stroke 1, 251 yds to Semi Rough, 8 yds left to pin
21                                                                                                      
22           3    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 5                                    in the hole for Bogey
23           3    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 4        stroke 4, 15 ft 4 in. to Green, 6 in. left to pin
24           3    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 3      stroke 3, 35 yds to Green, 14 ft 11 in. left to pin
25           3    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 2          stroke 2, 168 yds to Bunker, 31 yds left to pin
26           3    8    Ahmed, Skaik      Shot 1          stroke 1, 247 yds to Rough, 195 yds left to pin
27                                                                                                      
28           1  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 4                                      in the hole for Par
29           1  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 3        stroke 3, 14 ft 4 in. to Green, 9 in. left to pin
30           1  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 2      stroke 2, 56 yds to Green, 14 ft 10 in. left to pin
31           1  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 1         stroke 1, 314 yds to Fairway, 61 yds left to pin
32                                                                                                      
33           2  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 3                                      in the hole for Par
34           2  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 2       stroke 2, 15 yds to Green, 3 ft 11 in. left to pin
35           2  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 1           stroke 1, 230 yds to Rough, 14 yds left to pin
36                                                                                                      
37           3  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 4                                      in the hole for Par
38           3  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 3         stroke 3, 19 ft 4 in. to Green, 2 ft left to pin
39           3  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 2      stroke 2, 153 yds to Green, 17 ft 5 in. left to pin
40           3  100  Niall, Kearney      Shot 1        stroke 1, 287 yds to Fairway, 155 yds left to pin
41
```